# Renaming dataframe rows with element contained in string name of the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have this `DataFrame`, with row names unfortunately containing both integers and strings, for example '20210902_Rene_Nicole_OC2012A_Sample_0087_20uLinject_01'. I would like to rename the rows to contain just the sample number, the example above would just become '0087'.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['20210902_Rene_Nicole_OC2012A_Sample_0087_20uLinject_01',2.233,7.84554,10.222],['20210902_Rene_Nicole_OC2012A_Sample_0097_20uLinject_01',2.000,7.8666,10.000],['20210902_Rene_Nicole_OC2012A_Sample_0098_20uLinject_01',2.230,7.8500,10.005]],columns=('786.2323','800.3231','832.5699','850.0022'))
```

This creates the following `DataFrame`:
[image: df]

The desired output looks like this `DataFrame`:
[image: Desired resulting dataframe]

I have tried transposing the dataframe with the intention of renaming columns then transposing back at the end, and using the str.replace function to edit column names, but I think there are problems because the column name contains both integers and strings, and they change. If this had worked, I would do it again to delete the sample name "_20uLinject_01", though I am wondering whether there is a better way to do this.

```
df.transpose()
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('20210902_Rene_Nicole_OC2012A_Sample_', '')
#returns error: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"
```

Any ideas how to go about this? I have around 180 rows to rename, so it would be great to loop through or not have to do it manually for each row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.str.split("_").str[<index>]`. The code is as follows:

```
>>> df["786.2323"] = df["786.2323"].str.split("_").str[5]
>>> df
  786.2323  800.3231  832.5699  850.0022
0     0087     2.233   7.84554    10.222
1     0097     2.000   7.86660    10.000
2     0098     2.230   7.85000    10.005
```

Here the index 5 corresponds to the value you require.